# Gibbs-Helmholtz equation for finite changes ($\Delta$ operator)

Tags: thermodynamics, potential, differentiation, calculus

I have hard time understanding why Gibbs-Helmholtz equation holds for finite changes. That is why we can write:
$$\Delta \left(\frac{\partial{G/T}}{\partial{T}}\right)_p=-\frac{\Delta H}{T^2}$$

We differentiate $f=G/T$ which must be a function of $(T,p)$ as is denoted in partial derivative operator. Therefore:

$$\left(\frac{\partial{G/T}}{\partial{T}}\right)_p=-\frac{H}{T^2}$$ which in general is also a function of $(T,p)$. So why for can apply the $\Delta$ operator if the initial and final states and therefore Gibbs energies correspond to different temperatures? That is $G_1(T_1,p_0)$ and $G_2(T_2,p_0)$. Shouldn't
we write:
$$\Delta \left(\frac{\partial{G/T}}{\partial{T}}\right)_p=-\frac{H_2}{T_{2}^2} + \frac{H_1}{T_{1}^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

The derivation should go something like this:

At constant standard pressure, $$dG_{Product}=-S_{Product}dT$$and$$dG_{Reactant}=-S_{Reactant}dT$$So adding up the equations for the products and reactants in stoichiometric proportions, we have $$d(\Delta G)=-\Delta SdT=\frac{\Delta G-\Delta H}{T}dT$$So, $$\frac{\partial (\Delta G)}{\partial T}-\frac{\Delta G}{T}=-\frac{\Delta H}{T}$$or, equivalently, $$\frac{\partial [(\Delta G)/T]}{\partial T}=-\frac{\Delta H}{T^2}$$

Comment: Still I can't get why we must seperate the system into products and reactants. Shouldn't we have one function of Gibbs free energy that is $G(T,p,n_i)$ or because initially we have no products we can't put them in the argument of the function??

Comment: We are going from a initial state of pure reactants in separate containers to a final state of pure products in separate containers.

Comment: What do you mean by seperate containers? Isn't the reaction take place in the same container? So when we have a function $G(T,p,n_i)$ we can't say anything about reactions right? The only thing about particle changes is if there is a exchange of particles between the sytem and the surroundings?

Comment: The process between the initial state and the final state is unspecified, but part of this process will certainly involve introduction of the pure reactants into a reactor where a mixture of reactants and products exists; and it will also involve removal of pure products using appropriate separation equipment (e.g., semi-permeable membranes.  However, in the end, the pure products are in separate containers, and , at the beginning, the pure reactants start out in separate containers.  Google “van’t Hopf equilibrium box.”